# Unable to skip next input field with tabindex="-1"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have noticed the following behavior....

I have several (at least 4) input fields on a form. If I handle the "`blur`" event on the first input and set the "`tabindex=-1`" on the **NEXT** input field (inside that blur event handler using `$(selector).prop("tabindex","-1");`), then I press "tab" (with that first input field in focus), the blur handler fires, the `tabindex` gets set to "`-1`", but the field isn't "skipped"!!

Although, if you click back in the first input and hit tab again, it will then skip the second input.

Using the same scenario, if I instead set the "`tabindex=-1`" on the third field (in the blur handler for the first input), then start at the first input and hit tab, tab, it **DOES** skip over the third field.

This behaves the **SAME** way on **IE 11**, **Chrome** and **Firefox**....

There seems to be a "timing" issue. Evidently, the browser has already decided what field it is going to "`focus`" next, when it fires the "`blur`" handler (since setting the "`tabindex=-1`" on the **NEXT** field doesn't "skip" it).

Has anyone else seen this problem?

Thanks for any feedback!
Shayne

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to `keydown` event and check for key to be `tab`. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/0bb73hgg/).

```
<input type="text" id="first">
<input type="text" id="second">
<input type="text" id="third">

$(function() {
    $('#first').keydown(function(ev) {
    if(ev.which === 9) { //tab key
        $('#second').attr('tabindex', '-1');
    }
  });
});
```